# How to use jquery toggle to display/hide post replies?

Tags: jquery

I am wanting post replies to be hidden on page load, and then toggled on clicking link:

**html:**

```
<!-- the post div-->
<div class="post">
<!-- the post content -->
<div class="clicker">click me</div>
<!-- end of the post -->
</div>

<!--begin replies div -->

<div class="container">

<div class="reply">
text in here
</div>

<div class="reply">
text in here
</div>

<div class="reply">
text in here
</div>

</div>

<!--- end replies div -->

<!-- repeat again etc-->
```

**css:**

```
.container {
display: none;
}
```

**jquery:**

```
$(function() {
    $(".clicker").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.container').toggle('blind'); 
    });
});
```

**jsfiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/rwone/grBkm/9/ (solved solution)

Comment: Please also describe the problem (i.e. the behaviour you observe vs the one you want), not only your goal. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is with your usage of the `.closest()` function. It traverses up the DOM tree, starting at the selector element(s), looking for the first element that matches the selector. However, your `.clicker <div>` is the child of a sibling of your `.container <div>`, so you want to go up first to the `.post <div>`, and then across to `.container`.

You can achieve that by doing the following:

```
$(this).closest('.post').next('.container').toggle('blind');
```

Take a look at [an updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/grBkm/8/).

Comment: sorry, how to implement not in jsfiddle? i have copied and pasted exact javascript from http://jsfiddle.net/rwone/grBkm/5/ between `<script>` tags in head (below `<script src="/script/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>` and getting error in firebug `'ReferenceError: $ is not defined'`.

Comment: @user1063287 That suggests jQuery isn't actually being loaded; check that the relative path to the jQuery file is actually correct.

Comment: thank you, that solved that issue. functionality not working though, i will troubleshoot, but just want to check it is ok to copy/paste code directly from javascript section in jsfiddle (in between `<script>` tags?).  ie no other code changes need to be added?

Comment: @user1063287 You'll need to wrap it in a `$(document).ready(function() {// code from jsFiddle here})` call, since jsFiddle simulates that with the default `onLoad` selection.

Comment: it is not working (ie clicking does not trigger anything), there are no errors in firebug but there are warnings, quite a few for `TypeError: anonymous function does not always return a value` but they seem to be coming from the actual jquery file itself, i'm not sure if that means anything.

Comment: i can replicate it here:  http://jsfiddle.net/rwone/grBkm/7/ .  i think the issue is that the 'clicker' is within it's own div, whilst the class that it is controlling is in another div, so i think the `.next` is not working.

Comment: @user1063287 The HTML from your question doesn't exactly match that, and there's a very important distinction. In the original question, `.clicker` and `.container` are siblings, now they're not. Now the correct traversal is up from `.clicker` to `.post`, then across to `.container`: http://jsfiddle.net/rwone/grBkm/8/

Comment: yes, that is correct, in trying to make my code example clear i neglected to show the closing div that separated the clicker from the container. how do i traverse `up from .clicker to .post, then across to .container`?

Comment: @user1063287 Take a look at the jsFiddle I linked to, it has the updated solution (though I initially posted the wrong URL). If you edit your question to add the `.post <div>` back in I'll edit my answer to reflect that.

Comment: i have updated original post, and getting 404 on your last jsfiddle link.

Comment: Sorry, looks like I copied the entirely wrong thing: http://jsfiddle.net/grBkm/8/

Answer (score 0):

Try this link..It shows a good example.
http://papermashup.com/simple-jquery-showhide-div/

this should work..
use next() instead of closest()

$(this).next('.container').toggle('blind');